# How to read pointer values into an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have following struct

```
typedef struct
{
    char* city;
    int temp;
} Place;`
```

I am attempting to read in two values from a line into an array of structs.

The lines look like:

> Los Angeles; 88

I am attempting to read data into the array. Assuming my memory allocation is correct what is the correct way to read in these values.

**my code**

```
    void readData(FILE** fpData, FILE** fpOutput)
{
    char s[100];
    int index = 0;

    Place *values;
    values=malloc(size * sizeof(Place));
    if (values == NULL)
    {
        MEM_ERROR;
        exit(1);
    }


    for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
    {
        (values[a]).city = (char *) malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        if(values[a].city == NULL)
        {
            MEM_ERROR;
            exit(100);
        }
    }

    while(fgets(s, sizeof(s), *fpData)!=NULL)
    {
        sscanf(s, "%[^:]%*c%d\n", values[index].city, &values[index].temp);
        index++;
    }

    sortInsertion(values, size, fpOutput);

    free(values);
    return;
}
```

The city is not going into the array so I am assuming the part where it says values[index].city is incorrect.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: @hii There is a need to ensure the area for `city`. also `"%[^:]%*c%d\n"` : `:` typo --> `;`

Comment: remove sscanf, use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) on ';' to split the string and easily refer to the two datafields.  and apply some validation as @BLUEPIXY suggests

Comment: `Place *values;` only define a pointer. You need to change this to array like `Place values[100]`, or use `malloc`.

Comment: Also similar with `char* city;` inside the struct. Change this to `char city[100];`

Comment: @hii Just want to make sure that you aware with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data using semicolon `;` while your `sscanf` format using colon `:`, make sure this is same character. If your data really use semicolon, change `%[^:]` part in the `sscanf` format to `%[^;]`

Here my code and how I run it to show you that it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Place {
    char city[100];
    int  temp;
} values[30];

int main() {
    char s[100];
    int i=0, n=0;
    while ( fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin) != NULL ) {
        sscanf(s, "%[^;]%*c%d\n", values[n].city, &values[n].temp);
        n++;
    }
    printf("n=%d\n", n);

    for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
        printf("values[%d] = (%s, %d)\n", i, values[i].city, values[i].temp);
    }
}
```

This is how I run it on Linux:

```
% for a in `seq 1 3`; do echo "City-$a; $a$a"; done | ./a.out 
n=3
values[0] = (City-1, 11)
values[1] = (City-2, 22)
values[2] = (City-3, 33)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sscanf(s, "%[^:]%*c%d\n", values[index].city, &values[index].temp);
```

This will copy everything from the start of the line read up to the first colon (`:`) into the `city` array you allocated.  Your example input would seem to have a semi-colon (`;`), so you'll get the entire line in the `city` array and nothing in the `temp` field.

You don't do any input checking, so any too-long input line will get split into multiple (probably corrupted) cities.  You'll also have problems if there are not exactly `size` lines in the file, as you don't check to make sure `index` doesn't go past `size` while reading, and you assume you have `size` entries at the end without checking.